# WPF - Binding failing to a User Control Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a Control Items Group that is bound to an ObservableCollection. The ItemTemplate for each of the items works if it is set to a TextBlock as:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I created a User Control with a TextBlock within it. I want to pass the above "FirstName" to the User Control. I am trying to do this by defining a DependencyProperty in the User control code behind as:

```
public static DependencyProperty SomeValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "SomeValue",
  typeof(Object),
  typeof(SampleControl));

public string SomeValue
{
  get
  {
    return (string)GetValue(SomeValueProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    (this.DataContext as UserControlViewModel).Name = value;
    SetValue(SomeValueProperty, value);
  }
```

and in the MainWindow's ItemTemplate, I changed it to:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleTemplate">
  <local:SampleControl SomeValue="{Binding FirstName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But this does not work. I am not sure why this Binding is failing when the same Binding works fine for a TextBlock within MainWindow. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot I can see wrong and it could be any of these things breaking this:

```
public static DependencyProperty SomeValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "SomeValue", typeof(String), typeof(SampleControl), 
  new FrameworkPropertyMetaData(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomeValueChanged)));

private static void OnSomeValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ((d as SampleControl).DataContext as UserControlViewModel).Name = e.NewValue;
}

public string SomeValue
{
  get
  {
    return (string)GetValue(SomeValueProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue(SomeValueProperty, value);
  } 
}
```

Notice I am using a `String`, and not `Object`. And, doing extra work on changing values in the `PropertyChangedCallBack`. And, I am only doing the basics in the `SomeValue` POCO as the real work is done in `SetValue`. Also of note, I did not do any exception handling, which could be your error also...if set's `.Name` call fails in your current code, then `SetValue` never hits

Comment: The important thing to note here is that the setter of `SomeValue` is just a convenience to provide an easy way to set the value of the dependency property (it has other purposes, but they're not relevant here). The dependency property system can still change the value of the property without going through your setter. If you want to perform some action on every change, register a property changed handler like Justin suggests.

Comment: Thank you Justin and Tim. I do see the mistake and I have corrected it and it works fine when I pass a constant value as:
    
    <sys:String x:Key="fixedValue">"123"</sys:String>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleTemplate">
      <local:SampleControl SomeValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource fixedValue}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

But it does not work with Binding though:

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleTemplate">
      <local:SampleControl SomeValue="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

I keep getting the error: BindingExpression path error: 'FirstName' property not found on 'object'